# Dismissing NIB loaded with loadNibNamed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib

I'm loading a nib (XIB) correctly from within a view controller with the following code:

```
self.myView.view = (MyView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self.myView options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now, later on in my flow I have another `UIView` that gets displayed.  However, I ONLY want this view to be displayed once a certain condition exists AND `myView.view` has been removed from the current `self.view`.

What is the correct way to remove a subview that has been added to the main view as I've done above?  I can add my header and main of `MyView` if needed, but mainly just curious about the correct approach in general.

Thanks for the help in advance!  This is bugging me terribly!

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.myView.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Yeah, I would think that would be the obvious answer.  This doesn't seem to get executed.  Could it be because I'm setting up a `delegate` in MyView and its messing with who is calling the `removeFromSuperView`?

Comment: And the reason I'm setting a delegate in the view is because I have an `IBAction` in the ViewController that is using CoreAnimation to display another view.